# Multilayer networks with multi-type nodes in complex network analysis

Tags: graph, social-networking, complex-networks

I have a question which was not sure where to ask. I am working on community detection in complex networks and i want to study new articles about community detection in multi layer or heterogeneous multi-layer networks but i am not sure my problem is in which category?
I have 3 types of networks with different types of nodes. For example, one layer is about the connections between flowers, other layer is about connection of disease of flowers, and the third layer is about the drug for curing the disease of flowers. As it is obvious, we have 3 layers that nodes in each layer are from different types and there are edges between layers, for example, an edge between a flower and its disease. So, i think this is not a multiplex network since there are different types of nodes in layers and there are edges among different types of nodes between layers. Is this a multi-layer network? Do multi-layer networks support nodes from different types? Or is it a heterogeneous multi-layer network? I am not sure about the type of this network to search about it.
I ask these details to understand what kind of search should i do to find articles about community detection. I appreciate answers which help me.